How does Pong work?
One of the minigames is Pong, and the only thing I don't understand about it is how the angle and speed of the new balls are decided.
It seems to depend on the angle and speed of the ball that lost / won the round?
But sometimes it's just straight on like in the first round? Or perhaps I'm mistaken? Can anyone tell me the rules? Or is it just "it's like it just kept going"

Well, I beat the first Pong challenge finally, at like. 5-0, so it's also not necessary to lose any rounds? And without Boost, so that's not necessary either.
And it seems that it is like the angle is kept from the previous rounds, with a few limits, like if it's a straight on at the very top or bottom, it'll start from somewhere about halfway from the top / bottom respectively, but keep the angle.
